# How to run a pipeline if each time the requirements of a task changes?

Tags: python, luigi

I have a pipeline: F -> M -> S. Where F, M and S are tasks. I call luigi with task S. Task S requires M; and M requires F. But sometimes, M requires D, others times requires B. F, D an B are different, nothing alike, but the output of all these tasks can be used by M. Today we have 3 options, but with time this number will grow. Should I change all the tasks each time a new task is added to pipeline as an option, (for instance, we now have the code for task E, that sometimes will be required by M, and other times won't), or can I pass the task as a parameter (how?)?

Answer (score 0):

What you want is probably [Dynamic Dependency](https://luigi.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tasks.html#dynamic-dependencies) in luigi. I would have  something like this

```
class M(luigi.Task):
  def requires(self):
        # keep empty() or add any dependency which are not dynamically required

  def run(self):
      # Collect condition for each of the dynamic dependencies
      if(condition_for_task_F):
          s=yield TaskF()
      elif....
      else:
          s= yield TaskE()
```

And to answer your question  whether can you pass Task as a parameter. The Answer is might be possible with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3061/calling-a-function-of-a-module-by-using-its-name-a-string). But this must be absolutely prohibited since it breaks idempotence principle. This is bad programming. the better way is to  decouple dependency logic to another task like this.

```
 F,D,B,E -> Y -> M -> S
```

where  Y just calculates the  dependencies and pushes them to M.